# Use same mesh with different pose (including different Inverse Kinematics) in different scenes

Tags: rigging, linked-data, library-overrides

I am trying to use the same character with different poses in different scenes. I have managed to create a new scene as a “linked copy”, so changes to the mesh in the base scene are reflected in the target scene.

Now I want to change the pose in the target scene, while keeping the original pose in the base scene. And ideally, I would like to change some IK constraints in the target scene, because in the base scene they are set up to be handy for most normal poses, but in the target scene I want to experiment with some deliberately deviating poses.

I therefore created a copy of the base scene armature in the target scene, and now I am looking for a way to override the Armature modifier of the mesh in the target scene only to follow the target armature instead of the base armature. I assume this is possible with Library Overrides, but I fail to understand how to set up such an Override (or any Library Override in general) or to find another way to make the Armature modifier's Object property different in different scenes.